# Stateful and stateless react component

Tags: reactjs

What is it like to render stateful components inside stateless component? Does it affect the use case of stateless component?

Answer (score 2):

Each component goes through its own lifecycle and is independent regardless of whether they are rendered within a stateful or a stateless component.  Also a stateful component within a stateless component doesn't affect the parent component.

The only caveat to this is that is a component higher up in the hierarchy stops render by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` or extending `PureComponent`(doesn't re-render when no change in props or state) or `by using React.memo` for functional components. The children lifecycle methods or updates will also not be triggeres.

Answer (score 0):

**No, It doesn't.**

The life-cycle methods that are associated with a component that has state should work independently of where they are in the component hierarchy.